# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable en python con sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

escribo porque no logro solucionar un problema con una query que realiza mi API que esta hecha en Python. Este error igual no afecta el funcionamiento de la API pero quiero quitarlo igual porque se ve desprolijo o claramente no se programar con SQLAlchemy o Flask.

en mi `@app.route` tengo asi:

```
@app.route('/verificarincidencia/<idservice>', methods=['GET'])
@requires_auth
def verificarincidencia_get(idservice):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        checkincidencia = db.session.query(reclamo,reclamoservicioasignacionafectado,servicioasignacion).join(reclamo.reclamoservicioasignacionafectado, reclamoservicioasignacionafectado.servicioasignacion).filter(servicioasignacion.idservicioasignacion==reclamoservicioasignacionafectado.idservicioasignacion).filter(reclamo.idreclamo==reclamoservicioasignacionafectado.idreclamo).filter(reclamo.masivo==1).filter(reclamo.estado!='Solucionado').filter(servicioasignacion.idservicioasignacion==idservice).first()

return jsonify( {'reclamo': [elemento.as_dict() for elemento in checkincidencia] })
```

y luego de que realiza esa verificacion y que ese return no devuelve nada en al consola me tira este error

```
return jsonify( {'reclamo': [elemento.as_dict() for elemento in checkincidencia] })
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

entiendo que si no devuelve nada deveria entenderse que el objeto esta vacio y no es iterable, pero como puedo solucionarlo?? intente ponerlo asi:

```
if checkincidencia is not None:     
        return jsonify( {'reclamo': [elemento.as_dict() for elemento in checkincidencia] })
else:
    options = checkincidencia
    return jsonify(options)
```

pero sigue igual solo que ahora me dice que `return jsonify(options)` es no iterable.

Se entiende mi duda?? desde ya muchisimas gracias a la gente de la comunidad que siempre me ha ayudado!! Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En efecto, `first` devuelve `None`, que no es iterable, cuando la consulta no devuelve ningún valor.

Una buena manera de solucionarlo, y evitar comprobar cada consulta, es añadiendo un iterable vacío en la list comprehension que sólo se evaluará si el primer elemento (la consulta) es `None`.

```
return jsonify(
    {'reclamo': [elemento.as_dict() for elemento in checkincidencia or []]}
)
```